# How to add countdown timer into Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

I am using **FIREBASE DATABASE** and I want to add A **countdown timer** to be shown to all users **at the same time**.

How to perform that in a very simple way?

My database is like this:

```
time:"9000" //which represent the 9 seconds
```

`

I tried to do something like this but it only retrieves the beginning of the time with no update of time of the database. 
the overall idea is that I want every user to see the same time when he enters the activity

```
value= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("time");

    value.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long v= (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(v,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            show.setText("time : "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent i=new Intent(Main4Activity.this,OneActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }.start();
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

});

Comment: if you want everyone to see the same time then a timer should update the field in the database

Comment: yes, that's what I want. I want all to see the same time .

Comment: I am not professional, So what I should do know by codes??

Comment: It depends how you want to do it.. When does the countdown start? A user trigger? manually set off the countdown? when the activity opens?

Comment: Ok, 1-:if users equals 5>>check >>start countdown timer.2- time is controlled from the firebase. that means it is manually set

Answer (score 0):

This might/might not be what you want, as it depends on a few factors. (especially cost)

You can have firebase-functions be your timer but it has a maximum execution time of 540 seconds, and after a certain quota, are not free. 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

If you have a structure like this:

```
root
    - connectedUsers
        - userUid:true
    - time: <time> // put your time in ms here 
    - observedTime: 0
    - startTimer
```

then you will need to do a few things:

1: in onStart() / onStop() of your Activity, set/delete your user from connectedUsers via `ref.child('connectedUsers').child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(true/null);`

2: create 2 function triggers (pseudo-code)

```
exports.connectedUsers = functions.database.ref('/connectedUsers/{userId}').onWrite((event) => {
    // return db.child('connectedUsers').get() as promise
    // then check the childCount
    // if it's 5, return db.child('startTimer').set(true); 
    // otherwise return 0 
});

exports.timerFunction = functions.database.ref('/startTimer/').onWrite((event) => {
    // start a timer, make sure it's a promise
    // on each interval (seconds) call(not return) db.child('observedTime').set(timeLeft);
    // after timer is done, return promise
    // then return db.child('startTimer').delete(); 
});
```

3: inside your Activity onStart also add a ValueEventListener pointing to `ref.child("observedTime")` and set your Text with (don't forget to parse as string)

That's about it, as soon as 5 people are connected the function connectedUsers will trigger the timerFunction, which will start a timer and updating observedTime each interval, after that it will delete the triggerRequest.

Note, if one client loses connection, their timer will stop. There are more edge cases you would need to handle (what if a 6th client connects? or one leaves?)

If you don't want to use functions to do the countdown, you can of course have the client updating it, but that adds complexity (who updates the timer?)

Another solution could be that all users have their local timer on their phone, listen on the 'startTimer' node, and when it comes in they start their countdown. Someone(functions/client) would still need to post that request for everyone to observe, and clients might not be 100% sync

Comment: I really didn't work on firebase functions before so I don't know how to deal with. is there any other method to do ?.also are firebase functions added to the app or deal with the console?

Comment: functions are hosted online alongside other firebase services like storage, analytics.

Comment: ok during last weak i practices about functions so what is the meaning of promise??

Comment: Please look it up on youtube, there are 100x better explanations than what I could give. Basically its like a callback, but better

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //fetch test time in minutes
    //and convert that into milli seconds
    mTimerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("eTest").child(key).child("TestMinutes");
    mTimerRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = (Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class))) * 6000;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            //when timer will finish
            //submit marks to firebase and close this activity
            //once marks is been submitted to firebase then close the quiz
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("eTest").child(key).child("Marks").child(sIdHeader).setValue(Integer.toString(mScore));
            Intent intent = new Intent(QnA_Test_Activity.this, Attempt_eTest_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            QnA_Test_Activity.this.finish();
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
}
private void updateCountDownText(){
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
    mQnATimer.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

I hope this will help you,
just set minutes in firebase and this code will fetch minutes and convert them into millis and then implement timer.